# Initialize value of variable while declaration

Tags: java

Can somebody explain me why below program produce **10** and **0** ?. I would expected **10** and **10**;

```
public final class Testing {
    static int j = function1();
    static int i = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(j);
    }

    public static int function1() {
    return i;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` variables are initialized in the order they appear in the source code of the class. Therefore when `j` is initialized, `i` is still `0` by default, so `function1` returns `0` and `j` is initialized to `0`.

After `j` is initialized to `0`, `i` is initialized to `10`, and your `main` prints `10` and `0`.

[JLS 12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) :

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, **in textual order, as though they were a single block**.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... clear and perfect solution for me.

Comment: replace the order of the two lines:

    static int i = 10;
    static int j = function1();

This is because the memory of i (integer) is initialised with 0 before you make it 10.